# Data was not inserting in SqLite DataBase but Row count is increasing

Tags: android, android-sqlite, auto-increment

When I try to insert my data in my sqlite table, The inserted data is not inserting but the primary key is increasing and row count also increasing. Dont know  what the exact problem is. Please some one help what the issue is. I will add my code here. Pls some one help me

here I am adding to database

```
  mylistDataBaseModel = new MyListDataBaseModel();

                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemId(0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemName("");
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemPrice(0.0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemGst(0.0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setCategoryId(0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemCategoryName("");
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemPicture("");
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemcount(0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setListName(createList.getText().toString().trim());
                mylistDataBaseModel.setListItemcount(0);
                mylistDataBaseModel.setItemisAdded(0);

             //   Log.d("==============", "====" + createList.getText().toString().trim());
                 sqLiteDatabase = sqlLiteController.getWritableDatabase();
                  SqliteController.addMyListNameToDataBase(sqLiteDatabase, mylistDataBaseModel);
                 sqlLiteController.close();
```

and opearation in database is

```
public static void addMyListNameToDataBase(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, MyListDataBaseModel model) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN__ITEM_ID, model.getItemId());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME, model.getItemName());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE, model.getItemPrice());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_GST, model.getItemGst());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM__CATEGORY_ID, model.getCategoryId());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, model.getItemCategoryName());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_PICTURE, model.getItemPicture());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_COUNT_ID, model.getItemcount());
    Log.d("==============", "====" + model.getListName());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_MY_LIST_NAME, model.getListName());

    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_MY_LIST_COUNT, model.getListItemcount());
    contentValues.put(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.COLUMN_ITEM_IS_ADDED, model.getItemisAdded());


    sqLiteDatabase.insert(SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.MYLIST_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    System.out.println("Cart Summary one row has been inserted");
    UserNotification.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_MY_LIST_ITEM_ADDED, null);

}
```

this is my get data from table method

```
 public static ArrayList<MyListDataBaseModel> getMyListData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ArrayList<MyListDataBaseModel> allMyLists = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + SqliteItemsDataBase.NewUSerInfo.MYLIST_TABLE, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                int localId = cursor.getInt(0);
                Log.d("list","====localId====="+localId);
                int itemId = cursor.getInt(1);
                Log.d("list","====itemId====="+itemId);
                String itemName = cursor.getString(2);
                Log.d("list","====itemName====="+itemName);
                Double itemPrice = cursor.getDouble(3);
                Log.d("list","====itemPrice====="+itemPrice);
                Double itemGst = cursor.getDouble(4);
                Log.d("list","====itemGst====="+itemGst);
                int categoryId = cursor.getInt(5);
                Log.d("list","====categoryId====="+categoryId);
                String catName = cursor.getString(6);
                Log.d("list","====catName====="+catName);
                String itemPicture = cursor.getString(7);
                Log.d("list","====itemPicture====="+itemPicture);
                int itemsCount = cursor.getInt(8);
                Log.d("list","====itemsCount====="+itemsCount);
                String listName = cursor.getString(9);
                Log.d("list","====listName====="+listName);
                int listItemCount = cursor.getInt(10);
                Log.d("list","====listItemCount====="+listItemCount);
                int itemIsAdded = cursor.getInt(11);
                Log.d("list","====itemIsAdded====="+itemIsAdded);


                allMyLists.add(new MyListDataBaseModel(localId, itemId, itemName, itemPrice,
                        itemGst, categoryId, catName, itemPicture, itemsCount, listName, listItemCount, itemIsAdded));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return allMyLists;
}
```

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: yes, posting. please wait

Comment: What's the evidence for "not inserting"? How are you reading the database?

Comment: @laalto I added my Log statements in getDataFromTable method. Pls check..

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake that I got the data with some other column id instead of respected column id . That's my mistake